# How to blink flashlight when incoming call is ringing and stop flash blinking when ringing is over?

Tags: android

I want to blink my Android mobile flashlight when phone is ringing and flash blinking should be stopped on ringing time is over, on rejecting call or if I answer the call.

I have used broadcast receiver but not working perfectly.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    PhoneCallStateListener customPhoneListener;
    boolean entered = false;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    Camera camera;
    Camera.Parameters params;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("flash_setings", 0);
        telephony =
                (TelephonyManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        customPhoneListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(context);
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    public class
    PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        private Context
                context;
        Timer timer;
        TimerTask timerTask;

        public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(final int state, String
                incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.d("STATE", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
                    Log.d("ringing state",
                            "ringing");
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        Class
                                clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                        Method
                                method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        method.setAccessible(true);
                        ITelephony telephonyService =
                                (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager); // Checking incoming
                        call number //System.out.println("Call " + block_number); if
                        (sp.getBoolean("isenabled", true) == true) {
                            if (entered == false) {
                                entered = true;
                                Log.d("SOUND OFF :" +
                                        sp.getBoolean("flash_only_isenabled", false) + "", "");
                                if
                                        (sp.getBoolean("flash_only_isenabled", false) == true) {
                                    Log.d("SOUND OFF :" + sp.getBoolean("flash_only_isenabled", false) +
                                            "", "");
                                    audioManager = (AudioManager)
                                            context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("SOUND", "ON");
                                    audioManager = (AudioManager)
                                            context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
                                }
                                if
                                        (sp.getBoolean("flash_ring_isenabled", false) == true) {
                                }
                                if
                                        (camera == null) {
                                    try {
                                        Log.d("Camera ", "interval " +
                                                sp.getInt("flash_interval", 1) * 1000);
                                        String myString =
                                                "010101010101010101010101";
                                        long blinkDelay =
                                                sp.getInt("flash_interval", 1) * 1000;
                                        for (int i = 0; i <
                                                myString.length(); i++) {
                                            if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                                                camera =
                                                        Camera.open();
                                                params = camera.getParameters();
                                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                                                camera.setParameters(params);
                                                camera.startPreview();
                                                camera.stopPreview();
                                                camera.release();
                                                camera = null;
                                                try {
                                                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                camera = Camera.open();
                                                params =
                                                        camera.getParameters();
                                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                                                camera.setParameters(params);
                                                camera.startPreview();
                                                camera.stopPreview();
                                                camera.release();
                                                camera = null;
                                            }
                                        } 
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        if
                                                (camera != null) {
                                            camera.stopPreview();
                                            camera.release();
                                            camera =
                                                    null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) { //Toast.makeText(context,
                        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.d("STATE", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.d("STATE", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                    break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    }
}
```